# Как понять, из каких вершин должны состоять полигоны в 3Д модели (Obj модель)

Tags: python, pygame, 3d

Я делал свой 3D wareframe движок и был уже на шаге добавления полигонов но у меня возникла проблема
с их отображением т.к. я не могу сделать так чтобы полигоны состояли из соседних вершин (квадратом)
, у меня вершины соединяются по прямой и квадратов из полигонов не получается т.к. программа не знает какие вершины соединять (в каком порядке). Я использую чтение .obj файла и если строчка примерно равна вот этому:

v 1.543241 43.321 5.5324 - это значит что на координатах (1.543241x 43.321y 5.5324z) есть вершина

И у меня есть список с координатами вершин. Программа рисует либо просто точки на месте вершин либо какие-то корявые полигоны (потому что не знает какие вершины должны входить в состав полигона).

Код считывания координат вершин из файла:

```
#name = 'Deer.obj'
coords=[]
    with open(name) as obj:
        for line in obj.read().splitlines():
            #print(line)
            try:
                if line[0]=='v':
                    coords.append(line[line.index('v')+2:].split())
            except:
                pass
```

(Беспокоится о неверной работе функции Polygon3D я не считаю нужным т.к. я ее уже много раз проверял)
Отрисовка полигонов по координатам:

```
polyCords=[]
#con - счетчик вершин для отдельного полигона
#pol - сколько вершин должно входить в полигон
con=1
pol=pol
for ncl in coords:
    if con!=pol:
        polyCords.append(pos_convert(ncl[0],ncl[1],ncl[2], posS))
    else:
        con=1
        con+=1
        if len(polyCords)==pol:
            Polygon3D(polyCords, ang, clr=(randint(100,255),randint(100,255),randint(100,255)))
            polyCords=[]
```

Функция `Polygon3D` работает также как и функция `pygame.draw.polygon` только преобразовывает 3Д координаты в 2Д

1.Нарисовано точками

[image: Олень по 3Д точкам]

2.Полигонами по 4 вершины

[image: Олень с полигонами]

Comment: А секции `f 1/2/3` у вас ниже нет, где указано по каким конкретно вершинам треугольники строить?

Comment: @Kromster да , есть , просто я не знаю как эти строки использовать

Comment: Так эти-то строки и содержат информацию о том, как надо строить полигоны (на каких вершинах) ;-)

Comment: @Kromster можете пожалуйста объяснить как эти строки понимать? Просто f 98/1/98 4902/1/4902 100/1/100 как-то не похоже на координаты

Comment: `f 1/2/3` - значит что треугольник надо нарисовать на 1,2 и 3 вершинах. И так далее. Кажется вполне очевидным, нет? )

Comment: @Kromster f 1/2/3 - значит надо соединить 1 2 и 3 вершины?

Comment: Да. Так же не стесняйтесь, поищите и почитайте официальное описание формата OBJ - многое почерпнёте )

Comment: @Kromster f 98/1/98 4902/1/4902 100/1/100 - это как понимать?

Comment: Википедия в помощь - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj

Comment: @Kromster Ок, спасибо!

Comment: @Kromster Да , это и вправду помогло!